# How to create a class object from nested dictionary and iterate through it in python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, object, nested

I am learning programing by developing a script to automate tasks in Python. I need to code something that reads multiple sections with multiple variables from a configuration file and create a nested dictionary. The nested dictionary is the input of a class and use it allows me to create one object per section. The variables in each section give the attributes of my objects.
The configuration file can contain a variable number of section and specific number of variables in each section.
Configuration file is like this :

```
[SECTION_01]
name = 'name_01'
zone = 'zone_01'
size = 'size_01'
specific_to_SECTION_01 = ''

[SECTION_02]
name = 'name_02'
zone = 'zone_02'
size = 'size_02'
specific_to_SECTION_02 = ''
...
etc.
```

I get the nested dictionary I want and define it as an input of a class thanks to setattr() method.

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("ini_file.ini")

class MyClass(): 
    def __init__(self, dictionary)
        for section in dictionary:
            for k, v in dictionary[section].items()
                setattr(self, k, v)



my_dict = {}
for section in config.sections():
    if section.startwith('SECTION'):
        my_dict[section] = {}
        for key, value in config.items(section):
            my_dict[section][key] = value
```

But then i would like to define my objects from the sections and define the attributes with a for loop, it returns an error about iterating through the dictionary class. By the way, I am not sure to know how to define well the attributes while I can't have a good definition for my loop.

```
obj_dict = MyClass(my_dict)
for sect in obj_dict:
    obj_01_name = MyClass(my_dict).name
    obj_01_zone = MyClass(my_dict).zone
    ...
```

This returns `MyClass object is not iterable`. I find some topic about adding the `__iter__()` method but I get this `TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type MyClass()`. I have found other topics about adding `__next__()` but I don't see how to integrate it.
Otherwise, I can loop directly through `my_dict` but when I try to instance `MyClass()` in the for loop, it gives me only the last section.

Comment: What did you hope `sect` would be?` Your `MyClass.__init__` method never preserved the section names, so you don't have anything there to loop over. If you want `MyClass()` to be iterable, then yes, at the very least you'd have to implement `__iter__()` (as a generator, much, much easier than having a separate `__next__()` method), but **please include your attempt**, at the very least.

Comment: Please do include full tracebacks for your errors (in this specific case it was easy enough to figure out where it happened or how Python got there, but that won't always be the case), and please, include *expected output*. We can't help you here because we don't know what the expected output of your code would be.

Comment: it will be simpler to keep it as normal dictionary inside class - `self.data = dictionary` and later use `for sect in obj_dict.data: obj_dict.data[sect]['name']`.